# Does Wittgenstein's "The limits of my language mean the limits of my world" relate ontology with language?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology, wittgenstein, language, badiou

Since Badiou equates ontology with Mathematics, if both philosophers are to be taken verbatim, there's a triple equivalence to consider: ontology = Mathematics = language.

Comment: On W's *Tractatus* 5.6 see also [this post](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15059/if-the-limits-of-my-language-are-the-limits-of-my-world-then-how-can-it-be-th).

Comment: If we take it verbatim, "the limits of my language *mean* the limits of my world", and ontology is not "my world". Besides this, Tractarian Wittgenstein and Badiou have very different ideas of what "mathematics" and "ontology" are. Could you explain what exactly you expect from an answer? See [On Wittgenstein's Kantian solution of the problem of philosophy](https://www.tandfonline.com/eprint/m6Z4ihMEPbicHkDu3rrs/full) and [Ontology and Method in Wittgenstein's Tractatus](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2214349) on the relation of the limits of language to Tractarian ontology.

Comment: From an answer, I expect just new information I did not assemble originally, including of course very much welcomed corrections. I had the feeling this question could even sound outrageous, Just polishing my poor understanding of these 2 complicated philosophers.

Comment: Also, after reading your past ref. I suddenly realized that Wittgenstein has not equated ontology with language, but, as said, my world's limits = my language's limits, (still a bit extreme, though). Also, I think that world = ontology is not an admissible equivalence since ontology is just the study of beings (entities) as beings, and the world is all those beings.

Answer (score 3):

*Long comment*

See the original text into the [Tractatus](http://www.tractatuslogico-philosophicus.com/#node/n5-6):

> **5.6** The limits of my *language* mean the limits of my world.

This must be read in the context of W's view about the "un-sayable" :

> **5.61** We cannot think what we cannot think; so what we cannot think we cannot *say* either.

We understand the world through language, that mirrors facts, and there is no way to "step outside" language to compare the language with the world.

Having said that, for Wittgenstein mathematics is not equal to language.